# How to access custom property from User Profile using jquery

Tags: 2010, javascript, jquery, user-profile-service, spservices

**Environment** : SP 2010

I have a custom property in User Profile called `CompanyCode`.

I need to fetch this property using javascript/jquery in a master page. Can anyone let me know how to fetch custom property from user profile.

I used

```
var companyCode = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
      fieldName: "CompanyCode"
   });
alert(companyCode);
```

returned empty string.

Note :

I have also tried default properties but no result.

```
var companyCode = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
              fieldName: "CompanyCode"
           });
        alert(companyCode);
```

Let me know how can I achieve this?

**Edit**: Now I have taken SP.Profile.js file from 2013 environment and referenced it. Still facing issue.

Comment: is it necessary to use spservices?

Comment: no.. only client side and output is required.. may be anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. This can be achieved in 2 ways:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var soapEnv =
            "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> \
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
  <soap:Body> \
    <GetUserProfileByName xmlns='http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService'> \
      <AccountName>"+"DOMAIN\\UserID"+"</AccountName> \
    </GetUserProfileByName> \
  </soap:Body> \
</soap:Envelope>";

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://devsp10:2000/_vti_bin/userprofileservice.asmx",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            complete: processResult,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
        });
});

function processResult(xData, status) {
         var cCode ;
         $(xData.responseXML).find("PropertyData > Name:contains('CompanyCode')").each(function() {
            cCode = $(this).parent().find("Values").text();
         alert("cCode : "+ cCode);
      });       
}
```

OR Can be achieved by adding reference to [SPServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/) from codeplex.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');

function init(){

   var cCode;
   $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetUserProfileByName",
    async: false,
    AccountName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).find("PropertyData > Name:contains('CompanyCode')").each(function() {
        cCode = $(this).parent().find("Values").text();
        alert("Company Code : "+cCode);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is of retrieving user properties of current logged in user. you can read more in this [article](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-working-with-user.html) of how to modify the below code to obtain what you need.

```
(function($){

  $(document).ready(function(){         
    // Ensure that the SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before the custom code runs.
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadUserData, 'SP.UserProfiles.js'); 
  });

  var userProfileProperties;

  function loadUserData(){

    //Get Current Context   
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    //Get Instance of People Manager Class
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    //Get properties of the current user
    userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();

    clientContext.load(userProfileProperties);

    //Execute the Query.
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);

  }

  function onSuccess() {        

    alert(userProfileProperties.get_displayName());

  }

  function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert("Error: " + args.get_message());
  } 

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I couldn't find any reference to SP.UserProfiles.js, my environment is 2010 not 2013